# What is the perfect temperature for serving soup?

Tags: soup

I have read reports that 400 degrees Celsius is too hot. I've read reports that 10 degrees Celsius is too low. Who am I to believe?

Comment: Given the temps listed, I am not sure you are serious.  There is, however, a scale for proper soup serving temperature. Since the question has not been dealt with on this site before, I will answer below.  In the mean time, maybe you could edit your question to remove the exaggerated temperature range.

Comment: related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46427/what-is-the-temperature-range-for-food-not-to-burn-your-mouth

Comment: 400 C would melt lead, so, yeah, I think that's a bit warm.

Answer (score 2):

In general, and according to a few culinary school sites, clear soups should be served near boiling 210°F (99°C), cream or thick soups between 190°F to 200°F (88°C to 93°C), and cold soups: serve at 40°F (4°C) or lower.